# Преобразовать json

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

У модели `Plan` есть поле `objects`, которое хранится в базе в формате json

```
  def new
    @plan = Plan.new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @plans = @restaurant.plans
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json:  @plans.distinct.pluck(:objects) }
    end
  end

  def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(:restaurant_id, objects: [ :width, :height, :fill, :radius, :blendMode, :rotate, :strokeWidth, :stroke, :type, :x, :y])
  end
```

Когда вывожу `object` то получается массив в массиве:

```
{"objects":[[{"width":308,"height":248,"fill":"#fff","radius":0,"blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"rectangle","x":84,"y":46},{"width":260,"height":150,"fill":"white","blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"circle","x":497,"y":104},{"width":69,"height":51,"fill":"#fff","radius":0,"blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"rectangle","x":149,"y":112}]]}
```

Как можно вывести чтобы был только 1 массив?

```
{"objects":[{...}]}
```

Comment: а какого типа получается результат у этого выражения `@plans.distinct.pluck(:objects)`?

Comment: Какого вида у вас JSON в БД? Уж не массив ли часом?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman получается [[{...}]]

Comment: @D-side ну да массив

Comment: @D-side может можно как то вывести `@plans.distinct.pluck(:objects)` подругому, не массивом, а что то типа `@plans.objects`, когда в консоли делаю нечто подобное то он выводит то что нужно

Comment: вообщем нашел как можно отдавать то что мне нужно `@plans.find(33).objects`  но нужно как то искать id plan для каждого restaurants